# Mezuzah on indoor and outdoor archways

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

1. A mezuzah must be attached on the upper third of the doorway.
   How does one determine the height of the doorway when affixing a mezuzah on an archway? Till the very top, or only till the end of the straight doorposts?

[image]

2. Is a garden archway except from mezuzah?

[image: Garden Archway]

Comment: What is a "garden archway"? Why do you mention "indoor" vs "outdoor" archways? Are you talking about a pure archway (like the Gateway Arch) or one propped on straight posts (like the Arch of Titus)? Best to include a picture with labels to make sure everyone is on the same page. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I noticed all of your answers are posts from one site, so a quick check there reveals indeed a new post about arched doorways https://www.vaadmhk.org/mezuzah-on-an-archway-not-so-simple/ Remember it [is ok to ask a question if you know the answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/759) and please post an answer to it as well, but remember not to compromise on question quality when doing so. You should still define your terms and motivate the post.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first picture - an arched roof:

According to the Sefer קביעת מזוזה כהלכתה on page 390 he concludes that while it seems to be a Rashi/Rambam dispute, the Taz says that they both agree and the entire arch is counted towards the height.

(Whereas a simple reading would have Rashi saying this, and the Rambam excluding the arch, the Taz disputes this understanding of the Rambam).

He bases this on the Igros Moshe O"C Vol. 4 siman 105.

Regarding you second picture - an arch of hedges:

The same Sefer says on page 131 that a doorway made of a hedge needs a Mezuza without a Bracha - it would seem you'd put it towards the top of the metal post, a tefach away from the top of the (short) right hand side post.